# Using case statement in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, case

I haven't used case statements before and was wondering how to do the following.

I have a number of news pages, each having posts relevant to department, so the pages

```
/tynewyddnews
/woodsidenews
/outreachnews
/sandpipernews
```

On my home page I am grabbing the latest post from each of these and displaying them.

Post Model

```
def self.top_posts
#Array with each of the 4 departments - first record
top_posts = [
  self.tynewydd_posts.first,
  self.woodside_posts.first,
  self.sandpiper_posts.first,
  self.outreach_posts.first
]
#remove entry if nil
top_posts.delete_if {|x| x==nil}
return top_posts
end
```

tynewydd_posts for example is a scope

```
scope :tynewydd_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Ty Newydd"}, :order => "posts.published_on DESC"
```

So if i am reading a post on the home page from tynewydd and want to create a link to /tynewyddnews or i am reading a post from woodside and want to link_to /woodside I have been advised that a case statement may help, but I am unsure on what to use as parameters, so my attempt so far is

```
def public_news
 case Post.top_posts
  when :tynewydd_posts == 'Ty Newydd'
   link_to('...Read more', tynewyddnews_path)
  when :woodside_posts == 'Woodside'
  link_to('...Read More', woodsidenews_path)
end
```

end

And then in my view i can call the helper

```
<%= public_news %>
```

obviously a miserable attempt, firstly in examples I have seen a variable is being set when the case is being set?  if someone could give some advice on how to achieve this it would be much appreciated

Comment: What are the labels :tynewydd_posts and :woodside_posts, how you can compare constants with another constants ?

Comment: im very unsure here, i have updated question to advise that ty_newydd posts for example is a scope in my Post model. What do i compare to differentiate each post?

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant:

```
def public_news
  path = case
    when Post.tynewydd_posts then tynewyddnews_path
    when Post.woodside_posts then woodsidenews_path
    ...
    else default_path end
  end
  link_to('...Read More', path)
end
```

`when expression` will fire up when `expression` is evaluated to true

Comment: thank you, would you mind explaining whats happening here or point to a resource that would help me understand case statements better.Also every link points to tynewyddnews when i try this